# browser-specific CSS for mobile browsers

Tags: android, css, firefox, mobile, opera

How do I make media queries for the different mobile browsers (like Opera Mobile and Firefox) on the Android?  The CSS really breaks when I use certain browsers.

Comment: I think your question is really too wide. 

There are a number of articles on media queries on http://dev.opera.com/articles/tags/media%20queries/ for instance, but it's probably best if you post in specific more specific terms what your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly wit CSS, but you can use

```
// target mobile devices
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body { max-width: 100%; }
}

// recent Webkit-specific media query to target the iPhone 4's high-resolution Retina display
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    // CSS goes here
}

// should technically achieve a similar result to the above query,
// targeting based on screen resolution (the iPhone 4 has 326 ppi/dpi)
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi) {
    // CSS goes here
}
```

also you can define in HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />
```