# Can I build a Web Application which is compatible on all phones?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, css, html

I want to make a web application. Plus I want to make this application available to all phones using IOS and Android and place its icon over the home screen, as far as I came to know I can do so for Iphone, where I am confused is whether I have to make the same thing in a different manner for Android?

Comment: Why was this voted down? I wonder!

Comment: This is a very broad question and not suitable for StackOverflow. A useful answer would probably be a book, or at least a chapter of a book, and the answer would inevitably be more than a compact technical answer to a technical programming question.

Comment: yes u can do this using PhoneGap.

Comment: Can you suggest me some?

Comment: Phone Gap will give me an application I want to evade the boundations of hosting my app in the market or the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a web application then you will be fine, assuming you don't to port it as a native application.

Simply look at responsive website designs to account for the different screen sizes and resources like:

[browser-specific CSS for mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886970/browser-specific-css-for-mobile-browsers) and 
[Developing Sites for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html)

To help understand the CSS differences in the mobile browsers.

A good starting point is making use of the Twitter Bootstrap Framework for websites which is very responsive and looks great on all mobile platforms.

**Edit**

JQuery plugin to suggest the user adds the site to the home screen:

http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/ or http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Comment: In IOS can I give the user an option to place an Icon of my website over his home screen, I read that in terms of web apps for IOS I can do so, is there a way to port the same website and technique to Android?

Comment: Also I would like to know that if I make a web application in IOS can't I port it inside of a web view for my Android application?

Comment: Check my answer, i've added that request.

Comment: A web application isn't something you build just for one device browser, you build it for all - it's a website. Then you can use it on any device.

Comment: Exactly Ryan, I am searching for a way to do so in Android! Is it possible to place the icon of my webapp on the home screen and interact with the same like a native app?

Comment: Not really, unless you use things like: http://www.nimblekit.com/index.php which use js to get access to those features, but it's still far off from a native app.